# SQL Sever 2008 R2 - Transforming a table with xml list columns to individual rows in new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to write some SQL to help transition from one database to another.  It's gone well so far, but I ran into a problem I can't wrap my brain around.

Original:

```
Id (bigint) | ColA (XML) | ColB (XML) | ... | RecordCreation
```

The XML for each column with XML looks like the following:

```
<ColA count="3"><int>3</int><int>9</int><int>6</int></ColA>
```

For any particular row, the "count" is the same for each list, ColB will also have 3, etc., but some lists are of strings.

In the new database:
Id (bigint) | Index (int) | ColA (int) | ColB (nvarchar(20)) | ... | RecordCreation

So if I start with

```
5 | <ColA count="3"><int>9</int><int>8</int><int>7</int></ColA> | <ColB count="3"><string>A</string><string>B</string><string>C</string></ColB> | ... | 2014-01-15 ...
```

I need out:

```
5 | 1 | 9 | A | ... | 2014-01-15 ...

5 | 2 | 8 | B | ... | 2014-01-15 ...

5 | 3 | 7 | C | ... | 2014-01-15 ...
```

For each of the rows in the original DB where Index (second column) is the position in the XML list the values for that row are coming from.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit:
A colleague showed me a dirty way that looks like it might get me there.  This is to transfer some existing data into the new database for testing purposes, it's not production and won't be used often; we're just starving for data to test on.

```
declare @count int
set @count = 0
declare @T1 ( Id bigint, Index int, ColA int, ColB nvarchar(20),..., MaxIndex int)

while @count < 12 begin
    Insert into @T1
    select Id, @count,
    CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ColA.query('/ColA/int[sql:variable("@count")]/text()')) as int),
    CONVERT(nvarchar(20), ColB.query('/ColB/string[sql:variable("@count")]/text()')),
    ...,
    CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ColA.query('data(/ColA/@count)')) as int)
    From mytable
    set @count = @count + 1
end
```

Then I can insert from the temp table where Index < MaxIndex.  There'll never be more than 12 indices and I think index is 0 based; easy fix if not.  And each row may have a different count in its lists (but all lists of the same row will have the same count); that's why I went with MaxIndex and a temp table.  And I may switch to real table that I drop when I'm done if the performance is too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ColA XML,
    ColB XML
);
INSERT @MyTable (ID, ColA, ColB)
SELECT 5, N'<ColA count="3"><int>9</int><int>8</int><int>7</int></ColA>', N'<ColB count="3"><string>A</string><string>B</string><string>C</string></ColB>';

SELECT  x.ID,
        ab.*
FROM    @MyTable x
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT a.IntValue, b.VarcharValue
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  ax.XmlCol.value('(text())[1]', 'INT') AS IntValue,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ax.XmlCol) AS RowNum
        FROM    x.ColA.nodes('/ColA/int') ax(XmlCol)
    ) a INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  bx.XmlCol.value('(text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS VarcharValue,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY bx.XmlCol) AS RowNum
        FROM    x.ColB.nodes('/ColB/string') bx(XmlCol)
    ) b ON a.RowNum = b.RowNum
) ab;
```

Output:

```
/*
ID IntValue VarcharValue
-- -------- ------------
5  9        A
5  8        B
5  7        C
*/
```

Note: very likely, the performance could be horrible (even for an ad-hoc task)

Assumption:

> For any particular row, the "count" is the same for each list, ColB
>   will also have 3, etc., but some lists are of strings.

Comment: Well, it was quicker.  On the same data just doing the select without the insert mine took 58sec and the above took 7.  The problem is I didn't get the same number of results out and I don't know which is correct.  Mine returned 198167 rows and the above 198272.

Comment: Then you should check if there are rows having `/ColA/@count` greater than 12 (I saw this limit within your answer) : `SELECT * FROM @MyTable x WHERE x.ColA.exist('/ColA[@count > 12 ]') = 1 OR x.ColA.exist('/ColB[@count > 12 ]') = 1`. Also, you could those diff. rows by inserting results into tables and using EXCEPT thus: `SELECT * FROM #MyResults EXCEPT SELECT same columns FROM #YourResults` and `SELECT * FROM #YourResults EXCEPT SELECT same columns FROM #MyResults`.

Comment: Also, you should check if those `XML` columns (`ColA`, `ColB`) have the same number of elements: `SELECT * FROM @MyTable x WHERE x.ColA.value('(/ColA/@count)[1]', 'INT') = x.ColA.value('(/ColB/@count)[1]', 'INT')`. This query assumes that there is a single `/ColA` and `/ColB` element within every `XML` column.

Comment: Ah, I found it.  My assumption was incorrect (or at least the data I was working was).  15 IDs did not have a count attribute.  I guess I'll be using your method regardless of speed so I don't have to depend on that attribute existing.  Thanks for the help! (Your count was 105 more; 15 bad rows x 7 indices = 105.)

Answer (score 0):

A colleague showed me a dirty way that looks like it might get me there. This is to transfer some existing data into the new database for testing purposes, it's not production and won't be used often; we're just starving for data to test on.

```
declare @count int
set @count = 0
declare @T1 ( Id bigint, Index int, ColA int, ColB nvarchar(20),..., MaxIndex int)

while @count < 12 begin
    Insert into @T1
    select Id, @count,
    CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ColA.query('/ColA/int[sql:variable("@count")]/text()')) as int),
    CONVERT(nvarchar(20), ColB.query('/ColB/string[sql:variable("@count")]/text()')),
    ...,
    CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ColA.query('data(/ColA/@count)')) as int)
    From mytable
    set @count = @count + 1
end
```

Then I can insert from the temp table where Index < MaxIndex. There'll never be more than 12 indices and I think index is 0 based; easy fix if not. And each row may have a different count in its lists (but all lists of the same row will have the same count); that's why I went with MaxIndex and a temp table. And I may switch to real table that I drop when I'm done if the performance is too bad.